# prometheus not able to scrape uwsgi

Tags: uwsgi, prometheus

I am trying `prometheus` to scrape `uwsgi` container on port `7070`

I have following scrape job in `prometheus.yaml`

```
- job_name: 'kubernetes-pods'
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
    - role: pod
  relabel_configs:
    - action: labelmap
      regex: __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_(.+)
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
      action: replace
      target_label: kubernetes_namespace
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
      action: replace
      target_label: kubernetes_pod_name
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape]
      action: keep
      regex: true
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scheme]
      action: replace
      target_label: __scheme__
      regex: (https?)
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_path]
      action: replace
      target_label: __metrics_path__
      regex: (.+)
    - source_labels: [__address__, __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_port]
      action: replace
      target_label: __address__
      regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
      replacement: $1:$2
```

Also have annotations for `uwsgi` container :

```
  annotations:
     prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
     prometheus.io/port: "7070"
```

If I `curl http://<host_ip>:7070/metrics` from any container, it return json format metrics.

But when I do `curl http://<host_ip>:7070/metrics | promtool check metrics`.

I get `error while linting: text format parsing error in line 1: invalid metric name`

I think this is because `uwsgi` container expose metrics in `json` format and `prometheus` doesn't understand `json`.

What I need to do to make it scrapeable by `prometheus` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manage to do this with https://github.com/timonwong/uwsgi_exporter as a sidecar container.

```
  - name: uwsgi
    image: .....
  - name: uwsgi-exporter
    image: timonwong/uwsgi-exporter:latest
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 100m
        memory: 100Mi
    ports:
    - name: uwsgi-exp-port
      containerPort: 9117
      protocol: TCP
    args:
      - --stats.uri=http://localhost:7070/metrics
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.robustperception.io/writing-json-exporters-in-python
This should be your answer. So you need to write your JSON exporter

Comment: Does this JSON exporter need to be a part of `uwsgi` container ?

Comment: it depends only on you, can be done both ways. So you can add it to your container, or make it as a separate one (this way will be easier)